# Unable to detect "slide on" event on a button

Tags: ios

I am trying to detect a "slide on" event on a button. I want a user to be able to slide their finger over my several buttons and that an event triggers when they slide onto it. Right now it only works on "touch down" but doesn't detect the slide.

Here are 2 of my buttons. The "touch down" triggers a sound.

- (IBAction) play1 {

```
// Get the main bundle for the app
CFBundleRef mainBundle;
mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle ();

// Get the URL to the sound file to play
soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL (
                                           mainBundle,
                                           CFSTR ("1"),
                                           CFSTR ("wav"),
                                           NULL
                                           );

// Create a system sound object representing the sound file
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (
                                  soundFileURLRef,
                                  &soundFileObject
                                  );

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (self.soundFileObject);
}

- (IBAction) play2 {

// Get the main bundle for the app
CFBundleRef mainBundle;
mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle ();

// Get the URL to the sound file to play
soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL (
                                           mainBundle,
                                           CFSTR ("2"),
                                           CFSTR ("wav"),
                                           NULL
                                           );

// Create a system sound object representing the sound file
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (
                                  soundFileURLRef,
                                  &soundFileObject
                                  );

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (self.soundFileObject);
}
```

Any help to get this functioning by simply sliding onto the button would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are no "slide over" events on `UIButton`. You need either a touch up or touch down to get an event on the button itself.

What you can do is add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to your view and then check in `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged` in the delegate if the touch is over your button view (`- (CGPoint)locationInView:(UIView *)view`).